# Rewrite K64F internal Flash

Tags: arm, firmware, cortex-m, mbed

I'm getting started programming on ARM with FRDM-K64F devboard equipped with  mbed classic(not OS), and I would like to reprogram internal flash memory in order to "upgrade" the existent firmware with a new one placed on a MicroSD card, but i'm facing with some problems.

I'm using [FreescaleIAP](https://developer.mbed.org/users/Sissors/code/FreescaleIAP/) library to achieve write access but it seems not working: if i try to erase/reprogram memory areas already used by existing code (in my case approximately 0x0000-0x4000) it freezes during erase and in-flash firmware gets damaged (needs to be reflashed through usb).

Is there a way to perform this task? I would like to implement something like OTA firmware updates.

Comment: Obvious question: where is the flash-rewriting code running from at that point, and where are the currently-live exception vectors located?

Comment: @Alex Did you get any further with this? I'm also looking into it at the minute.  I've found that Kinetis provide a "RAM flashloader" on their chips from manufacturing which allows Kinetis MCUs to flash themselves from RAM, but I have yet to dig into this further. See this pdf: http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/user_guide/KFLLDRUG.pdf  Any more information you found would be appreciated.